# Cache-Control and Expires doesn't Work

Tags: .htaccess, cache-control, http-caching

I set up cache-control and expires headers via .htaccess but already it doesn't load from browser cache. When I enter the URI, I am waiting for load from web site.

URI: http://www.btgmaslak.com/static/images/main_container_background_11.jpg

Comment: Post the relevant .htaccess lines, it will be more helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me. The subsequent request is loaded from cache.

This is what you are sending down in the header:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Expires: Tue, 29 Jun 2010 08:50:09 GMT
```

Comment: How did you check is subsquent request loaded from cache ?

Comment: It works for me in both IE and Firefox. You can use http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to check that it is loaded from browser cache (You should see a 304 response). NB: Originally I thought that it didn't work in Firefox but then I realised that I had left the cache disabled in the web developer toolbar so apologies for any confusion caused by my earlier answer!